# Intuition behind inequality for measure of $\liminf$ and $\limsup$

Tags: measure-theory, inequality, intuition, limsup-and-liminf

For a set $X$ with a $\sigma$-algebra $\xi \subseteq \mathcal{P}(X)$ and $\sigma$-additive $\mu: \xi \rightarrow [0, \infty]$. The following inequality holds for $(A_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \in \xi^\mathbb{N}$:

$$
\mu({\liminf}_{n \rightarrow \infty} A_n) \leq {\liminf}_{n \rightarrow \infty} \mu(A_n)
$$

and under the assumption of $\mu(X) < \infty$ we also get:

$$
{\limsup}_{n \rightarrow \infty} \mu(A_n)\leq \mu({\limsup}_{n \rightarrow \infty} A_n) 
$$

I was able to prove these inequalities, but can't seem to develop a  deeper intuition. Is there any way to better understand why these statements are true?

Comment: At the risk of being rude, I don't think a deep intuition is needed; I think they are just obvious. For example, $\liminf_n A_n$ represents the elements that are in all of the $A_n$'s past some point. So clearly the measure of the set of these elements is less than the liminf of the measures of the $A_n$'s.

Comment: @mathworker21 I understand, that the $\lim \inf$ contains all the elements which are in all but finitely many of the $A_n$, but to me it's not obvious why the measure of these elements is always smaller or equal to the $\lim \inf$ of the measures...

Comment: Don't think of it as "all but finitely many". Think of it as "past some point". Let's pretend that $\liminf_{n \to \infty} A_n$ happened to be all elements belonging to $A_{10} \cap A_{11} \cap A_{12} \cap \dots$. Then $\mu(\liminf_n A_n) \le \mu(A_i)$ for each $i \ge 10$ and in particular, it is $\le \liminf_i \mu(A_i)$.

Comment: In reality, part of $\liminf_n A_n$ will also be $A_{12}\cap A_{13} \cap \dots$. But this doesn't matter. Each of these "parts" of $\liminf_n A_n$ will have measure at most $\liminf_i \mu(A_i)$.

Comment: No. $\liminf_n A_n \subseteq A_1$ is (in general) false. You should spend some time thinking about these things. In particular, try to connect the proof you have to intuition.

Answer (score 1):

Well, let's focus on the first inequality. The idea is simple: on the left-hand-side one is taking the intersection of the sets from some moment, while on the right-hand-side one is taking the smallest size of the sets from some moment. If you consider $X := X_1\cap \cdots \cap X_n$, there is no way that $|X| > |X_i|$ for some $i$, right? The same reason here, and all you need to do is to fit it in a limit and measure theoretic setting.